# EcoModeller creates duplicate class members

Tags: mdriven

Often (but not consistently) the EcoModeler creates duplicate class members (methods in this case). This of course causes extra work to cleanup the dupes. It often happens after changes to a model class.

The guids are identical, so I don't see why the code generator would create the dupes. Any ideas about how to avoid the generating of the duplicates?

Example:

[image]

//Rolf

Answer (score 0):

At this point we have been unable to repeat this.
We have recently changed how codegen is called from VS to facilitate async behavior but I do not know if this issue is related to that or not.

Please continue to provide details on the situations that lead this or any thing that can help us repeat.

Comment: > "At this point we have been unable to repeat this. "  Possibly also this could be a side effect of having non-eco attributes in the model. I will try again to see if it persists after cleaning up those aliens. (but please, add support for regular C# fields and properties. That would make the MDriven Framework ideal as an "app infrastructure" even in process intensive applications like processing CAD (Rhino3D) as I dabble with. Bold modeller handled Delphi attributes so elegantly...  (hint, hint) ;-)